Getting socket connect time out error when connecting to sap hana from google big query
I can connect to SAP Hana database from my laptop using Jupyter Notebook.
However, when I try to connect from Google Big Query, I am getting socket connect time out error. The same code works fine when I run from Jupyter Notebook from my laptop. Am I missing any config?


You are not getting a 'socket timeout'. You are getting a 'socket connect timeout'. Not the same thing.  Accuracy please. And don't post pictures of text here. Post the text.
